# toad locks folders from editing

Tags: toad

Say I have test.sql opened in Toad and I close it. It seems Toad still 'looks' at the location of this file. Namely, after closing it, I can edit the file itself, but not the folder it is in, as attempts to do so result in the error message "The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program".

Closing the file doesn't help, ending the connection in which I opened it doesn't help. But closing Toad does the trick, so I'm guessing Toad still has the location of the file memorized.

My issue is that I do not want to close Toad to edit the name of the folder. Does anyone know if this is possible? Is there for example an overview of which locations are in use/looked at by Toad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete the folder if it is Toad's [current directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx). As a workaround you can browse to a new folder location in a Toad open dialog. You may need to actually open a file from that new location. As I Google it there's a property of the open dialog used to not change the current directory. It's too late to change for the release underway (12.10), but I'll log a bug report to revisit this for the next release of Toad.

Comment: Opening a file from another location didn't work. Is that what you meant, or is there some other way to set/change Toad's current directory.

Comment: It works here for me. I opened a file and closed it. I attempt to delete the directory containing that file and I get an error as you did. In the Editor I opened another file from another location that is not a subfolder, etc. of the folder to delete. In Windows Explorer I can now delete the folder in question.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried it again and now it works. I probably did something wrong the first time (or still had the folder or some other file in it open). Also thanks for logging a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 12.0.0.61 after exporting a data set. I tried opening a random file from another location, but that did not work in my case.

One workaround that I did find to be successful is to open the FTP utility and manually change the current folder. When opening the FTP utility in TOAD, the "local system" location will default to the current folder. In my case, I just went up a level and that releases the hold on the folder I'm trying to modify.